# How to decode and encode transactions by using substrate?

Tags: sdk, substrateinterface

I want to decode blocks and transactions from the Node. I want to use https://github.com/paritytech/substrate . But I can not find methods about it. Could you tell me where it is ?

Answer (score 1):

Are you referring to something like this:

```
let block = node_primitives::Block::decode(&mut &block_data[..]).unwrap();
```

https://github.com/paritytech/substrate/blob/ded44948e2d5a398abcb4e342b0513cb690961bb/bin/node/executor/tests/basic.rs#L896